# Could not locate named parameter Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my dao method in which i try to get user details from database :

```
public UserInfo findUserInfo(String userName) {
    String sql = "Select new " + UserInfo.class.getName() + "(u.username,u.password) "//
            + " from " + User.class.getName() + " u where u.username = :username ";

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
    query.setParameter("username", userName);

    return (UserInfo) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

And when i try to execute it i get this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [username]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:493)
    at org.spajic.stefan.springhibernatesecurity.dao.UserInfoDAO.findUserInfo(UserInfoDAO.java:33)
    at org.spajic.stefan.springhibernatesecurity.dao.UserInfoDAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c14aad39.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at org.spajic.stefan.springhibernatesecurity.dao.UserInfoDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3fdca957.findUserInfo(<generated>)
    at org.spajic.stefan.springhibernatesecurity.authentication.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:25)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 36 more
```

And here is User class and UserInfo class as well. User is hibernate entity and UserInfo is model that i use.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", length = 36, nullable = false)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}

public class UserInfo {

   private String userName;
   private String password;

   public UserInfo()  {

   }

   // Do not change this constructor, it used in hibernate Query.
   public UserInfo(String userName, String password) {
       this.userName = userName;
       this.password = password;
   }

   public String getUserName() {
       return userName;
   }

   public void setUserName(String userName) {
       this.userName = userName;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
       return password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }

}
```

Any help ?

Comment: can you show me the mapping and table structure

Comment: could you share with us your `User` and `UserInfo` model?

Comment: i added them in question

Comment: try **u.userName**

Comment: In my UserInfo class i changed userName to username everywhere and it still throws same error

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the property is named UserInfo:userName in your POJO and your are trying to use username

I mean you are using a small 'n' instead of a caps 'N'

Comment: In my UserInfo class i changed userName to username everywhere and it still throws same error

Comment: You are trying to mix User and UserInfo. While you have marked the class "User" with the @Entity annotation the class "UserInfo" is not marked with any such annotation. I think that is the reason why the spring is not detecting this class during a package scan and you are getting this errors

Comment: any suggestion how to annotate UserInfo class ?

Comment: I think the UserInfo class is redundant. If you did mark it as @Entity than it would mean a new table for it and it would be unnecessary. There is also no relationship between these 2 classes other than having similarly named properties. I would suggest you get rid of UserInfo class and just use "User" alone

Comment: i will try that, but i would really like to know why isnt this working

Comment: This is not working because UserInfo is not a Entity and Hibernate cannot find it. Nor does it have any relation with User. A relation with User would be through some property and you would be using the annotations ManyToOne or ManyToMany or some such over that property

Comment: When i try to do this :
Query query = session.createQuery("from Users where username = :username ");

I get an error : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not mapped

Comment: i found out that i make mistake in defining package for scaning hibernate beans, i fixed it and now it works

Comment: Yes this is another problem with Hibernate, if the correct package is not being scanned it does give a misleading error message.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps , query accept even positional parameters :

maybe you can try `u.username = ?1` in query
and `query.setParameter(1, userName);` setting parameter

Anyway you can get the result to the **User** object and use that , i think you don't need **UserInfo** .